# Convolution of two Gaussians is a Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I know that the product of two Gaussians is a Gaussian, and I know that the convolution of two Gaussians is also a Gaussian. I guess I was just wondering if there's a proof out there to show that the convolution of two Gaussians is a Gaussian.

Comment: Hint: what's the Fourier transform of the convolution of two functions?

Comment: The first assertion is not true.

Comment: @Shai: Yes it is

Comment: @Amit: No (at least, for independent random variables). Why do you think it is?

Comment: As @sivaram suggested, taking the FT of both Gaussians, multiplying them, and IFTing the product yields the convolution of both Gaussians, which is a Gaussian in itself. That means that the FT of any Gaussian is a Gaussian (true), and that the product of both FTs (which are both Gaussians) is also a Gaussian, therefore, the product of any Gaussian is a Gaussian.

Comment: @Shai: And if you don't believe me, here's a link: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Gaussians_Closed_Convolution.html

Comment: @Amit: I meant that it's not true for random variables. That is, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal rv's, then $XY$ is not a normal random variable. See, for example, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html

Comment: @Shai Covo: But "Gaussian" by itself just means the function, not random variables distributed according to the function.

Comment: @wnoise: You are quite right. However, this is a source for confusion: http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.soft-sys.matlab/2009-03/msg04203.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fourier Transform will help you out to conclude that the convolution is also a gaussian.

Comment: I know that the product of the two FT of Gaussians is also a gaussian, and that is also equivalent to the FT of the convolution of two gaussians. Do you think, to show that the convolution of two Gaussians is a gaussian, it would be easiest to take the FT of both, multiply, and take the IFT of the product?

Comment: yes :) [ some extra characters to reach the minimum ]

Comment: @Mait: Yes that is the best way out.

Answer (score 7):

1. the Fourier transform (FT) of a Gaussian is also a Gaussian
2. The convolution in frequency domain (FT domain) transforms into a simple product
3. then taking the FT of 2 Gaussians individually, then making the product you get a (scaled) Gaussian and finally taking the inverse FT you get the Gaussian

Answer (score 4):

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) for two common alternatives.

Comment: That link is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this pdf file](http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/2003-003.pdf) can help you.

Comment: The link seems to be down.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proof for product of multivariate Gaussian PDFs in here. Maybe this can help:
http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/2003-003.pdf

Comment: It would be good of you give a synopsis of the proof here and then provide a link.