# Sum of two independent normal distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

If $X_i$, $i =1,2$ are independent and have normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma_i ^2$. Show that $X_1 + X_2$ has a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: You can compute the convolution of the densities directly, or you can compute the characteristic functions. The characteristic function of the sum of independent distributions is the product of the characteristic functions.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. And is the distribution of a random variable completely determined by its characteristic function?

Comment: Yes, the Fourier transform is invertible.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18646/convolution-of-two-gaussians-is-a-gaussian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use moment generating function $$M_{X_1+X_2}(t)=\exp(\sigma_1^2t^2/2+\sigma_2^2t^2/2)=\exp((\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)t^2/2)$$ and so $X_1+X_2\sim N(0,\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)