# A convolution integral involving Gaussian density

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, convolution, gaussian

Can the following integral be simplified to a closed-form expression:
$\int_a^r \phi(x; \mu_1) \Phi(r-x; \mu_2) dx$, where $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are the density and distribution function of Gaussian with unit variance. I would like to be able to compute this without resorting to numerical qudrature.

Comment: Knowing that the convolution of Gaussians is Gaussian, can't you use integration by parts? See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18646/convolution-of-two-gaussians-is-a-gaussian).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, 1), i = 1, 2$, and they are independent. Then

$$ \begin{align} &~~~~~  
\int_a^r \phi(x;\mu_1) \Phi(r-x; \mu_2) dx \\
&= \int_a^r f_{X_1}(x) \Pr\{X_2 \leq r-x\} dx \\
&= \int_a^r \Pr\{X_2 \leq r-x|X_1 = x\} f_{X_1}(x) dx \\
&= \Pr\{X_2 \leq r - X_1, a < X_1 < r\} \\
&= \Pr\{X_1 + X_2 \leq r, X_1 < r\} - \Pr\{X_1 + X_2 \leq r, X_1 < a\} 
\end{align} $$

So depends on what "closed-form" solution means.

Here note that
$$ (X_1 + X_2, X_1) \sim \mathcal{N} 
\left(\begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 + \mu_2 \\ \mu_1 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right)$$

So the integral itself can be expressed as the difference of two bivariate normal CDF in general. If bivariate normal CDF is considered not a closed-form solution, then this will imply that this integral has no closed-form solution in general.

Comment: BGM, Are you using $X$ and $Y$ instead of $X_1$ and $X_2$ in your solution?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the notation. I just edit it back to make it consistent