# Probability of three correlated gaussian variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, closed-form

Given three standard gaussian random variable $X,Y$ ($X$ and $Y$ are independent) and $Z$ with
$$X,Y = \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
$$Z = Y-X$$
and  $a,b,c \in \Bbb R$

> Is it possible to calculate analytically this probability $$\Bbb
>   P(X<a,Y<b, Z<c)$$

(by analytically, I mean we can write this probability by using basic mathematical operations and standard normal probability function***s*** $\Phi_n(\mathbf{z};\mathbf{0}_n, \mathbf{I}_n)$)

I compute the covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ of $(X,Y,Z)$, which is
$$\mathbf{\Sigma} = \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & -1\\
   0 & 1 & 1 \\
   -1 & 1 & 2 \\
   \end{pmatrix}$$

but this covariance matrix is unluckily singular.

Perhaps there is a clever way to decompose the region $\{X<a,Y<b,Z<c \}$ into several regions that can be analytically calculated?

Comment: Your (still singular) covariance matrix should be $\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & -1 \\
   0 & 1 & 1 \\
   -1 & 1 & 2 \\
   \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @Henry thank you, I corrected this typo!

Comment: So $X$ and $Y$ are independent, right?

Comment: When explaining what do you mean by analytically you used $\Phi_n(z;0_n, \Sigma)$. Shouldn't it be $\Phi_n(z;0_n, I_n)$ since you defined $\Sigma$ to be something else afterwards?

Comment: @JPMarciano Exactly, I mean $X,Y$ independent and $I_n$ instead of $\Sigma$

Comment: The region $\{(x,y) : x < a, y < \min\{b, x+c\}\}$ doesn't seem to play well with the rotational invariance of the standard bivariate Gaussian. I'm not optimistic there will be a simple expression for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll share my progress until now.

For short, we will define $\Phi(x)=\Phi(x;0,1)$, that is, the cummulative distribuition function of the Standard Normal and we use $\phi(x)=\Phi'(x)$ for the pdf. Using Bayes' Theorem, the independence of $X$ and $Y$ and the fact that $Z=Y-X$ we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X<a,Y<b,Z<c) &= \mathbb{P}(X<a)\mathbb{P}(Y<b,Z<c|X<a) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(X<a)\mathbb{P}(Y<b,Y<c+X|X<a) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(X<a)\mathbb{P}(Y<b)\mathbb{P}(Y<c+X|X<a,Y<b).
\end{align*}

Let's calculate

$$\mathbb{P}(Y<c+X|X<a,Y<b)=\mathbb{P}(c+X\geq b)\mathbb{P}(Y<c+X|X<a,Y<b,c+X\geq b) + \mathbb{P}(c+X< b)\mathbb{P}(Y<c+X|X<a,Y<b,c+X< b).$$

See that
$$\mathbb{P}(Y<c+X|X<a,Y<b,c+X\geq b)\geq\mathbb{P}(Y<b|X<a,Y<b,c+X\geq b)=1,$$
i.e.,
$$\mathbb{P}(Y<c+X|X<a,Y<b,c+X\geq b)=1.$$

Moreover, define

$$L:=\mathbb{P}(Y<c+X|X<a,Y<b,c+X< b)=\mathbb{P}(Y<c+X|X<\min\{a,b-c\},Y<b).$$

Let's define $d:=\min\{a,b-c\}$. Then

\begin{align*}
L&=\mathbb{P}(Y<c+X|X<d,Y<b)\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^d \int_{-\infty}^b 1_{\{y-x<c\}}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}dy dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^d e^{-x^2/2} \int_{-\infty}^b 1_{\{y-x<c\}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}dy dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^d e^{-x^2/2} \mathbb{P}(Y<x+c) dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^d e^{-x^2/2} \Phi(x+c) dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^d \phi(x) \Phi(x+c) dx
\end{align*}

Finally, we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X<a,Y<b,Z<c) &= \mathbb{P}(X<a)\mathbb{P}(Y<b)\mathbb{P}(Y<c+X|X<a,Y<b) \\
&=\Phi(a)\Phi(b)(\mathbb{P}(c+X\geq b) + \mathbb{P}(c+X< b)\mathbb{P}(Y<c+X|X<a,Y<b,c+X< b)) \\
&=\Phi(a)\Phi(b)((1-\Phi(b-c)) +\Phi(b-c)L) \\
&=\Phi(a)\Phi(b)(1-\Phi(b-c)(L-1)) \\
\end{align*}

I don't quite know how to deal with this $L$ yet. I'll try to think about that more later. Maybe we can use some idea of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4249341/a-convolution-integral-involving-gaussian-density).

Comment: Thank you very much! If I begin from the last formula of $L$, we can do $$L = \int \phi(x) (1- \Phi(-c-x))dx  = \Phi(d) - \int \phi(x) \Phi(-c-x))dx$$
The second term can be expressed as the difference of 2 bivariate normal probabilites as in the post you proposed.
$$$$
I will see how you get the $L$

Comment: @NN2 Nice, later I'll add that to my answer. I hope everything else is ok. If you find any errors let me know.

Comment: Thank to your answer, I found a way to cut the probability region $(X<a,Y<b,Y-X<c)$ into smaller regions that can be analytically calculated, and the answer depends on value of $(a,b,c)$. The problem is simpler if we plot $(X,Y)$ over the $Oxy$ and study the surface of probability.  $$$$ Suppose $a,b>0$, there are at least 4 cases: $(c>b,-c<0<a)$, $(c<b,-c<0<a)$, $(c<b,0<-c<a)$ and $(c<b,-c>a)$. For example, the case $(c>b,-c<0<a)$, we have
$$\Bbb P(X<a,Y<b,Y-X<c) = \Bbb P(X<a,Y<B) - \Bbb P(Y-X>c,Y<b)$$
And $\Bbb P(X<a,Y<B)$ ,$ \Bbb P(Y-X>c,Y<b)$ can be expressed as a function of $\Phi_2$